# Limit of Fraction of Polynomial Proof

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$.  I need help proving the following statement:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{p(x)} = 0$$

I'm complete lost and don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: A polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ can be written in the form
$$
p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\cdots+a_n x^n,\quad x\in\mathbb{R},
$$
where $n\geq 1$ and $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are constants such that $a_n\neq 0$. Now show that

- if $a_n>0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)=+\infty$,
- if $a_n<0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)=-\infty$.

In either case the conclusion is that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{p(x)}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$p(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0\;,\;\;a_n\neq 0\,\,,\,\,n\in\Bbb N:=\{1,2,\ldots\}\implies$$

$$\frac{1}{p(x)}=\frac{1}{x^n}\cdot\frac{1}{a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\ldots+\frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{x^n}}\;\;\;\;(**)$$

It is now a simple exercise to show that for any constant $\,k\,$ , we have that

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{k}{x^n}=0\;,\;\;\;n\in\Bbb N$$

Finally, just apply arithmetic of limits in (**) and you're done.

Comment: Elegant proof..